# WCF: Error al intentar serializar el parámetro cuando se envía una subclase

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Buenas, estoy trabajando sobre una solución que emplea System.Runtime.Serialization para la definición de DataContracts en las entidades que se utilizan para la comunicación del cliente con el servidor.

Cuando intenté utilizar una ClaseGral para que se puedan enviar diferentes entidades en una sola función, me dio el siguiente error (en el ejemplo, invocando miFuncion con un parámetro del tipo Subclase):

> Error al intentar serializar el parámetro http://tempuri.org/:param. El mensaje de InnerException fue 'No se espera el tipo 'Entidades.Subclase' con el nombre de contrato de datos 'Subclase:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Entidades'. Si está usando DataContractSerializer, intente usar DataContractResolver o agregar tipos no conocidos estáticamente a la lista de tipos conocidos (por ejemplo, usando el atributo KnownTypeAttribute o agregándolos a la lista de tipos conocidos que se pasa a DataContractSerializer).'. Consulte InnerException para obtener más información.

El código que usé es el siguiente:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace Entidades
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class MiEntidad
    {
        //datos
        public static void miFuncion(ClaseGral param){
            //código
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public abstract class ClaseGral
    {
        //datos
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Subclase : ClaseGral
    {
        //datos
    }
}
```

¿Qué necesitaría modificar en mis clases para que funcione bien? No tengo claro a qué DataContractSerializer se refiere el error o dónde configurarlo.

Comment: Hola achecopar. Lo ideal es que nos ayudes a reproducir tu error. Por lo tanto, te sugiero modificar el código que has incluído de modo que realmente sea un [mcve]. Si sigues el enlace, allí explica cómo se logra eso.

Comment: Bien, lo haré, se ve que me falta algo de código que está configurado en algún lado, pero no me dio el tiempo de encontrarlo. Gracias y aviso cuando haya editado

Comment: Para tener ese ejemplo completo hay que agregar código para configurar e invocar el método a través de WCF, cosa que ya está hecha en la solución que uso. Como ya pudieron darme una respuesta que solucionó el problema, lo dejo así, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el atributo `KnownTypeAttribute` se especifica en las clases base para indicar al serializador `DataContractSerializer` (el de por defecto de WCF), qué subtipos de esa clase debe reconocer. Tu problema se puede resolver aplicando el siguiente código en tu clase `[KnownType(typeof(Subclase)]`

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace Entidades
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class MiEntidad
    {
        //datos
        public static void miFuncion(ClaseGral param){
            //código
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Subclase)]
    public abstract class ClaseGral
    {
        //datos
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Subclase : ClaseGral
    {
        //datos
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso lo resolvió!